# Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

Good day, I'm new to coding & facing a weird problem that I can't solve by my own, please see my code below.

```
const Cart = require('../model/cart');
 
    exports.addToCart = (req, res) => {
        Cart.find({user: req.user._id}).exec((error, data) => {
            if (error) return res.send(error);
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
                const product = req.body.cartItems.product;
                const addOne = data.cartItems.find(c=>c.product == product);
                if(addOne){
                    Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ "user" : req.user._id, "cartItems.product" :product},{   
                        "$set":{
                            "cartItems": {
                                ...req.body.cartItems,
                                quantity : addOne.qunatity + req.body.cartItems.qunatity,
                            }
                        }
                    }).exec((error,data)=>{
                        if (error) return res.send(error);
                        if (data) return res.send(data);
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ user : req.user._id},{
    
                        "$push":{
                            "cartItems": req.body.cartItems
                        }
                    }).exec((error,data)=>{
                        if (error) return res.send(error);
                        if (data) return res.send(data);
                    });
                }        
            }
            else {
    
                const cart = new Cart({
                    user: req.user._id,
                    cartItems: [req.body.cartItems]
                });
                cart.save((error, data) => {
                    if (error) return res.send(`Something went wrong ${error}`);
    
                    if (data) return res.send(data);
                }) 
            }
        })
    };
```

1. I am getting an error on

   const addOne = data.cartItems.find(c=>c.product == product);
2. But by my logic code should not go inside the if(data) condition because the data is empty for the first entry. It should go to the bottom to the else code.

Comment: Just because `data` is defined doesn't mean it has a `cartItems` property

Comment: You seem to log your `data`. What does it contain when the error is thrown? Does it have a `cartItems`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But by my logic code should not go inside the if(data) condition
> because the data is empty for the first entry. It should go to the
> bottom to the else code.

Your `if` statement condition doesn't save you from your error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` because "data" contains any kind of value (exclude -> null, undefined or 0) but your expected "cartItems" don't exist at your "data" object.

You can try following code snipets to debug your code:

```
console.log(data.cartItems) // will return undefined
console.log(data) // doesn't contain "cartItems"
```

If `cartItems` is important for your condition use:

```
if(data && data.cartItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

For #2 in your post, it is not likely that your `data` fails the truthy test: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Notice that `if ({})` is truthy. Even an empty JSON response would be truthy.

Since you logged data, please share it's value. It's always best to provide all possible data as part of your question.